# Symfony + Compass, config.rb

Tags: php, symfony

Now I have `app/config/config.yml`:

```
filters:
    cssrewrite: ~
    sass: ~
    compass:
        apply_to: "\.s[ac]ss$"
        no_line_comments : true
```

and in my main file :

```
@import "compass";
@import "modules/_ads.scss";
@import "modules/_buttons.scss";
```

but when I use command `php app/console assetic:dump --watch` and changing for example `_buttons.scss` then compass does not see changes and doesn't recompile the main file. I think I must create a configuration file (`config.rb`), but I dont know how to write/link that to the symfony configuration file.

Answer (score 1):

The answer you are seeking you will not find.

The only solution we could come up with to overcome this issue is inserting a space or a new line in the main file and save it so that compass CSS will senses the change and recompile the main file with included files too.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use SASS on one of my last symfony2 projects with assetic and came to the conclusion that it's not worth the hassle as it's currently in a not very developer-friendly state. Because the files aren't recompiled I had to resort to the sass binary for recompilation and watch the recompiled css files. And that didn't worked as neatly as I'd have liked.

At the end my team and I broke the application apart in an indepented frontend (pure SASS and requirejs goodess ;-) ) version with the symfony2 project serving as a RESTful data layer.

Answer (score 0):

Yap I had the same problem with SASS.
After each change in a subfile I edited a dummy comment in the main File

```
/* asd */
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't have to make any change in your main file as long as you `touch` it. A simple save works like a charm.

You could also build a shell script that touch the main file every X seconds (although I don't like this solution).